# Stuck with modular implementation of Angular/fire messaging: How to make onMessage function work?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire2

I hope you are well, I would like to ask for help from the community as I have been stuck with the modular implementation of @angular/fire messaging for a few days now.

First of all, there is no official documentation to follow, as the page where there should be documentation seems to be just an empty skeleton:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/messaging.md

I've tried to build on their examples, which appear in the same repository:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/samples/modular/src/app/messaging/messaging.component.ts

And based on its "documentation" parent firebase,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Messaging, getToken, onMessage } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { EMPTY, from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { share, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messaging',
  template: `
    <p>
      Messaging!
      <code>{{ token$ | async | slice:0:12 }}<ng-container *ngIf="(token$ | async) !== null">&hellip;</ng-container></code>
      &nbsp;<code>{{ message$ | async | json }}</code>
      <button (click)="request()" *ngIf="showRequest">Request FCM token</button>
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class MessagingComponent implements OnInit {

  token$: Observable<any> = EMPTY;
  message$: Observable<any> = EMPTY;
  showRequest = false;

  constructor(@Optional() messaging: Messaging) {
    console.log('messaging', messaging);
    if (messaging) {
      this.token$ = from(
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js', { type: 'module', scope: '__' }).
          then(serviceWorkerRegistration =>
            getToken(messaging, {
              serviceWorkerRegistration,
              vapidKey: environment.vapidKey,
            })
          )).pipe(
            tap(token => console.log('FCM', {token})),
            share(),
          );
      this.message$ = new Observable(sub => onMessage(messaging, it => sub.next(it))).pipe(
        tap(token => console.log('FCM', {token})),
      );
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  request() {
    Notification.requestPermission();
  }

}
```

And so far I have only been able to register the service worker in the app and request the token,

This works if it returns me a correct token for the device,

But the one I can't get to work at all is the **onMessage** function, I don't get any notification.

I have tried it as a listener only for javascript, nothing.

```
listen() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
      this.message=payload;
    });
  }
```

I changed it to subscriber rxjs, just like the example, and neither

```
this.message$ = new Observable(sub => onMessage(messaging, it => sub.next(it))).pipe(
        tap(token => console.log('FCM', {token})),
      );

this.message$.subscribe(msg=>console.log('msg', {msg}));
```

And I send notifications to this token in 2 ways:

Through the firebase cloud messaging console where it says to send a test message and I put the token received and nothing.

I've also done it via the fcm API using postman.
[Screenshot](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1100/format:webp/1*vdZG3BG6f-YViagMa85K6A.png)

Please community, can you help me with any way that you have made Angular/fire's **onMessage** function work as I feel totally lost and I don't see where to keep trying.